# Windows 7 trusted root certificate updates

Tags: ssl, certificate

this is a general question on Windows 7.  MSFT officially stopped support for Windows 7 on 1/18/2020 unless you cough up money for extended support.  I noticed that some trusted root CA certificates are expiring in the next year (including a Microsoft certificate).  Will these certificates be automatically updated or will I need to manually update them?

I assume that MSFT will stop pushing out updates.  What will happen when I try to establish an SSL session with an enitity presenting the MSFT cert as part of its signing chain?  For example, an MSFT root cert expires in my certificate store on 12/31/2020.  However MSFT issues a new cert that expires on 12/31/2040.  I assume that I do not get it due to Windows 7 not being supported.  On 1/1/2021 will any attempt to establish an SSL session fail with someone presenting the updated MSFT cert (expires on 12/31/40) due to the root CA not validating because it is expired on my box?

Comment: Does MS issue _any_ TLS certs? Their websites appear to use Baltimore Cybertrust, and the Azure doc I found indicates it uses GoDaddy and Digicert. MS _does_ provide the root for _code-signing_ certs, but if timestamped (as recommended for years now) code signatures remain valid after the signing cert chain expires. And signatures on updates aren't an issue if there aren't any.

Comment: They do, Windows Update for Windows Defender seems using some sort of Microsoft Root CA.